# Understand auto function pointer types from lambda expressions

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto* fptr_a = +[](int i){ return i+1; };
    std::cout << "fptr_a(10): " << fptr_a(10) << std::endl;
    
    auto fptr_b = +[](int i){ return i+10; };
    std::cout << "fptr_b(10): " << fptr_b(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/* Output
fptr_a(10): 11
fptr_b(10): 20
*/

/*
gdb) ptype(fptr_a)
type = int (*)(int)

gdb) ptype(*fptr_a)
type = int (int)

gdb) ptype(fptr_b)
type = int (*)(int)

gdb) ptype(*fptr_b)
type = int (int)
*/
```

Why do `fptr_a` and `fptr_b` have the exactly same type even through one uses `auto*` and the other use `auto`? Also, which usage is preferred: `auto* fptr_a` vs `auto fptr_b`?

Comment: Because they are not capturing lambdas, hence are usual functions.

Comment: This is the same as `int i; auto ptr_a = &i; auto* ptr_b = &i;`. Is there a reason you would expect `ptr_a` and `ptr_b` to have different types?

Comment: @user17732522, no. I am just curious.

Comment: Please read the [ask] help page. I think the title here could use improvement.